# Cannot adjust logarithmic curve using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve, logarithm

I am trying to plot an adjustable *logarithmic curve* with `ggplot2`. From various Stack Overflow posts I was able to create this:

```
key <- c(1,2,300)
value <- c(10, 20, 300)
dummyData <- data.frame(key, value)

# ggplot graph plotting
graph <- ggplot(dummyData, mapping = aes(x=key, y=value))+
  stat_smooth(
    method = 'nls',
    formula = 'y ~ a * log(x) + b',
    method.args = list(
      start = list(a = 1, b = 1)
    ),
    se = FALSE
    )
print(graph)
```

However, no matter what extreme value I put the `start = list(a = 1, b = 1)` line, I couldn't adjust the logarithmic curve at all.

Comment: Your code works fine, what is the issue?

Comment: @Duck the issue is that the logarithmic curve is not being adjusted as I change the `a` and/or `b` value (via `start = list(a = 9999, b = 9999)`)

Comment: I think the `start` parameter just initializes the fit but it will still try to converge at the optimal fit (which is dictated by the data and therefore isn't changing). So if you want to coerce the line, maybe you could add additional datapoints or constrain the fit with other parameters.

Comment: @DanAdams What are the other parameters that I can constrain the fit? Also, is there a way for me to tell it not to converge at the optimal fit?

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but you could check `?nls` which leads to `?nls.control` which tells us that you can limit the number of iterations using `maxiter = 1`. But this begs the question of *why* you want to force a sub-optimal fit to some arbitrary parameters. Maybe if you explain your situation a bit more you could get another more rational solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this enabling the lower/upper options from `nls()`. As you can see the curves have changed:

```
library(ggplot2)
# ggplot graph plotting 1
graph <- ggplot(dummyData, mapping = aes(x=key, y=value))+
  stat_smooth(
    method = 'nls',
    formula = 'y ~ a * log(x) + b',
    method.args = list(
      start = list(a = 1, b = 1),
      lower = c(1, 1),
      upper = c(1, 1),algorithm = "port"
    ),
    se = FALSE
  )
print(graph)


# ggplot graph plotting 2
graph <- ggplot(dummyData, mapping = aes(x=key, y=value))+
  stat_smooth(
    method = 'nls',
    formula = 'y ~ a * log(x) + b',
    method.args = list(
      start = list(a = 999, b = 999),
      lower = c(999, 999),
      upper = c(999, 999),algorithm = "port"
    ),
    se = FALSE
  )
print(graph)
```

Outputs:

[image]

[image]

Or this:

```
# ggplot graph plotting 3
graph <- ggplot(dummyData, mapping = aes(x=key, y=value))+
  stat_smooth(
    method = 'nls',
    formula = 'y ~ a * log(x) + b',
    method.args = list(
      start = list(a = 1, b = 1),
      lower = c(1, 1),
      upper = c(10, 20),algorithm = "port"
    ),
    se = FALSE
  )
print(graph)
```

Output:

[image]